# Identifying the verb(-phrase) and object in a sentence

Tags: verbs, word-order, syntactic-analysis, objects

What is the verb(-phrase) and the object in the following sentence:

"Many of them were able to begin buying their own homes."

```
Case 1: 
    -verb(-phrase): were able
    -object (infinitive clause): to begin buying their own homes

Case 2:
   -verb(-phrase): were able to begin buying
   -object: their own homes
```

So "Case 1" or "Case 2"?

I would be really grateful for an answer. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I like analysis 1, but I think the verb is *able to*. "Did they bicycle over?" "No, they were not *able to*."

Comment: I have no formal training in grammatical analysis, so I'm not proposing this as an answer, but my gut feeling is to say that Case 2 is probably correct.

Comment: The verb phrase fills the function of predicate, which is "were able to begin buying their own homes". So your second case is correct.

Comment: @BillJ I don't see how the "so" necessarily follows from your first sentence... (not saying your conclusion is wrong necessarily, but that I don't understand your reasoning)

Comment: @SteveES Well spotted! The VP includes the object so the OP's second case should include the NP "their own homes" as part of the VP.

Comment: If you're an 11-year-old and want to impress your teacher, giving them Alan Munn's university-level analysis is possibly a bad idea. Note that even BillJ's less full version is neither 'Case 1' nor 'Case 2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence *Many of them were able to begin buying their own homes* contains two clauses, and therefore at least two verb phrases, so asking what "the verb phrase" or "the object" is is problematic.

The first clause in the sentence is the whole sentence. The first verb phrase is:

- *were able to begin buying their own homes*.

The pair of words *were able* by itself is not a syntactic unit, and therefore is not a phrase on its own.

The word *able* in this clause is an adjective that takes an object, the infinitival clause *to begin buying their own homes*.

The second clause in the sentence is the infinitival clause:

- *to begin buying their own homes*

Technically this clause has two verb phrases:

- *begin buying their own homes*

and

- *buying their own homes*.

This latter verb phrase contains the verb *buying* which takes an object, *their own homes*.

As in the case of *were able* the strings of words *to begin buying* or *begin buying* are not syntactic units, and therefore not phrases on their own.

The word *to* is not typically considered part of the main verb phrase, since it functions more like an auxiliary verb in terms of its syntactic position.

Comment: Yes, but the OP was only asking about the upper VP.

Comment: I would like to thank everybody for his/her answer. Alan, thank you very much for your very extensive answer. However, I'm not sure if I have understood the answer correctly. If I just perform a "first"-level analysis, analyzing the first clause, which is the whole sentence, is it correct to say: the infinitival clause "to begin buying their own homes" is the object of the verb "were"?

Comment: @Sinushyperbolikus No, that's not correct. "to begin buying their own homes" is the object/complement of the adjective "able".  The adjective phrase "able to begin buying their own homes" is the object/complement of "were".  I'm using object and complement interchangeably here, to mean "phrase that combines with a word to form a new phrase" although some people prefer to distinguish them in various ways. You can see this in StoneyB's tree, which I agree with (although I would use  different labels for some of the phrases.)

Comment: Alan, thank you very much for your reply. I got it now.

Comment: Alan, I'm sorry but just a last question. If I consider the sentence "My neighbour has started to begin buying new equipment", is it then correct to say that "to begin buying new equipment" is the object of the verb "has started"?

Comment: @Sinushyperbolikus Not quite. It's the object of the verb "started". "has" is an auxiliary verb that forms its own verb phrase with "started to begin buying new equipment".  As a rule of thumb, a string of adjacent verbs never forms a single verb, but forms multiple verb phrases each contained inside the other.

Answer (score -1):

SUPPLEMENTAL to Alan Munn's EXCELLENT ANSWER:

Here's a diagram of what Alan Munn is talking about:

[image]